# OpenGL Render front and back faces with different shading for 3d modeller

Tags: opengl, shading, model

I'm working on a simple 3d modeller and I would like to render the back facing triangles a bit darker, to easier differentiate between front and back faces. Like you can see in most modelling applications. How does one achieve is?

Should I enable back face culling and render the primitives and then enable front face culling, rotate the normals by 180 degrees and render the primitives again? Is this a practical approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fragment shader receives the [`gl_FrontFacing` system-defined input value](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#System_inputs). It will be `false` if the fragment was generated from a back-facing triangle, and `true` otherwise. So you can use that in your shader to determine how to generate a color value.